# Revoke Existing Facebook Permissions and Reconnect user to Facebook with new permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a React application that connects my users to their facebook account with certain permissions.

Now before connecting to the Facebook account, I want a way to be able to revoke existing permissions before connecting with new permissions but it appears to be not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
async connectFacebook(){
 window.FB.getLoginStatus(function (res1) {
        let { status } = res1;
        if (status === "connected") {  //This means the user has been connected to facebook previously, at this point I want to be able to revoke the existing permissions once the logout function below is called.
            window.FB.logout(function (res2) {  //This seems to logout the user but doesn't revoke the permissions. I don't know why. I want the permissions revoked immediately the window.FB.logout function is called.
                logInFacebookUserWithNewPermissions();  //Then, the new permissions should come up on the consent screen when the window.FB.logIn function is called again.
            });
        } else {
            logInFacebookUserWithNewPermissions();
        }
    });
}
```

The reason I really need the existing permissions to be revoked before presenting a new permissions consent screen again is because adding new permissions are not working once the user has logged in, which is very weird.

Any solution to the above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"This seems to logout the user but doesn't revoke the permissions. I don't know why."_ - because that's not what logging out does. If you want to remove permissions, you need to do that via an API call, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking

Comment: _"is because adding new permissions are not working once the user has logged in"_ - they should get asked for any new permissions you added to the scope, once the login dialog gets called again. If that is not working for you, then maybe you should rather try and investigate what exactly is the problem there, instead of looking for workarounds.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your response. So, here is my problem. I initially started with these permissions ```const facebookLoginScopes = ["email", "public_profile"]``` and then updated the permission scopes to ```const facebookLoginScopes = [ "email","public_profile","pages_read_engagement"]``` all in dev mode and the new permission I added never reflected. I kept getting error that I need permission ```pages_read_engagement``` to perform the task I need. And I have already requested for it. It's kindda weird

Comment: But you did actually call the login dialog again with this modified scope, yes?

Comment: @CBroe I called the ```window.FB.login``` function with the updated permission but the login dialog never came up. It just logs me in automatically with the old permission scopes. That is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Can't tell what's going wrong there, based on the snippet alone. But the approach to log the user out isn't the right one to begin with. If anything, when you have a connected user, you should check whether they already granted you the necessary permission(s) - and if not, call the login dialog. Same as you would, if they were not logged in at all yet.

Comment: @CBroe After authentication on the frontend with the JS SDK I requested for a long-lived access token using this endpoint ```https://graph.facebook.com/${graphAPIVersion}/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=${process.env.FB_APP_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.FB_APP_SECRET}&fb_exchange_token=${access_token}``` could that be the reason updated permissions are not reflecting when ```window.FB.login``` is called again? Also I noticed ```window.FB.logout()``` throws an error that it cannot be called without an ```access_token```. Could all these be the reason?

Comment: No, long or short lived token should have nothing to do with this. And yes, logging out requires a valid user access token - so if you are getting that message here, it most likely means that `status === "connected"` is based on outdated information. `getLoginStatus` might be giving you a cached result, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/#servers